# css content without pseudo-class

Tags: css

I wrote a class with content but seems content just work for pseudo-classes.

How to modify my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/fuRKC/

```
button.follow{
    content: 'Follow';
}

button.followed{
    content: 'Unfollow';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. `content` only works with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes.
Just make your css like this:

```
button.follow:before{
    content: 'Follow';
}

button.followed:before{
    content: 'Unfollow';
}
```

Comment: I thought 'before' causes my content fells out of my button.

Comment: Unless you use Opera, which does support the contennt property in normal elements.

Comment: @StephanMuller: I am on Opera 15 and it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I've seen it happen, not sure which version. But that's all irrelevant anyway, just use the pseudo-elements

Comment: @StephanMuller I checked with opera 12.16 Linux, was fine.

Comment: @StephanMuller: Maybe it was working in earlier versions and they changed it. But the thing with usage of pseudo elements is as usual **IE <9** :(

Answer (score 9):

By [current CSS specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content), the `content` attribute only applies to `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. There is an old proposed extension, [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), which would allow the property to apply to real elements, too. The proposal is however ten years old. It has only been implemented in Opera, except for the special case where the `content` value is an URL expression, interpreted as referring to an image – this is supported by Chrome and Safari, too.

Moreover, even the limited support wouldn’t do much good here, since the extension does not seem to work on Chrome when the element is a button, and on Opera, the generated content appears as such, not within a button widget.

Since your `button` elements have empty content, you don’t really need the extension, since for empty content, adding content is equivalent to replacing content. So in this case, you would just need to use `button.follow:before`, as in Kippie’s answer. Note, however, that this means that the button appears as completely empty when CSS is disabled.

So whatever might be the reason for using generated content, instead of button text in HTML, a more robust approach would be to change content with JavaScript. JavaScript can be disabled, of course, but you can use actual button text as fallback, e.g. `<button id=follow>Follow</button>`, and replace the content when JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

*"The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content."*

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

More info:

http://css-tricks.com/css-content/